# How can I create a view where the middle is not blurred

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Does anybody have an idea how I can create a view that is similar to the image attached? I'm using a `Stack` component with the `mobile_scanner` package, but I don't understand how I can leave the center of the screen without opacity.

[image: preview]

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Material(
  child: Stack(
    fit: StackFit.expand,
    children: [
      ColorFiltered(
        colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
            Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8), BlendMode.srcOut), 
        child: Stack(
          fit: StackFit.expand,
          children: [
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  backgroundBlendMode: BlendMode.dstOut), 
            ),
            Center(
              child: Container(
                height: 200,
                width: 200,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```